# Selected row gets cleared when data in table is updated

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I have created a TableView in JavaFX and have noticed that when I select a row, the selection gets cleared, as soon as the item in the table gets updated i.e. the data stored in the item gets updated. I have created a minimal example that can be run from your workspace. In the code, I have the Main class, that creates the UI, adds data to the table, and then generates a random string that is used to replace the old value depending of the ID of the table row. I also have the Person class that contains the model of the table view.

I have tried storing the selected row and then just selecting it again as soon as the selection clears, but this does not feel like a viable solution, but more like a hack.

The  Main class:

```
public class Main extends Application
{

  private TableView<Person> table = new TableView<Person>();

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
  {
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
    primaryStage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
    primaryStage.setWidth(450);
    primaryStage.setHeight(500);

    final Label label = new Label("Address Book");
    label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

    table.setEditable(true);

    TableColumn<Person, Integer> IDCol = new TableColumn<>("ID");
    IDCol.setMinWidth(100);
    IDCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, Integer>("ID"));

    TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
    lastNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
    lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("lastName"));

    table.getColumns().add(IDCol);
    table.getColumns().add(lastNameCol);

    final VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.setSpacing(5);
    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table);

    ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    addDataToTable();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    launch(args);
  }

  private void addDataToTable()
  {    
    //If the table has data in it, then we must check if the ID already exist, so that we can replace it.
    //else, we just add the items to the table in the first run.
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
    {

      @Override
      public void run()
      {
        while(true)
        {
          ObservableList<Person> data = generateData();
          try
          {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
          } catch (InterruptedException e)
          {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
          }

          if(table.getItems().size() > 0)
          {
            //first we cycle through the data in the generated list
            //then we cycle through the data in the table itself.
            //if the data is found, we replace it, and break from the loop.
            for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
            {
              for(int j = 0; j < table.getItems().size(); j++)
              {
                Person newPerson = data.get(i);
                Person currentPerson = table.getItems().get(j);

                if(newPerson.getID() == currentPerson.getID())
                {
                  final int J = j;
                  //now we replace it if it is the same
                  Platform.runLater(new Runnable()
                  {

                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                      table.getItems().set(J, newPerson);
                    }
                  });

                  break;
                }
              }
            }
          }
          else
          {
            //When modifying the data on the table,w e do it on the platform thread, 
            //to avoid any concurrent modification exceptions.
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable()
            {

              @Override
              public void run()
              {
                table.getItems().addAll(data);
              }
            });
          }
        }
      }
    };

    Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
    thread.setDaemon(true);
    thread.start();
  }

  private ObservableList<Person> generateData()
  {
    ObservableList<Person> values = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
      Person oPerson = new Person(i, randomStringGeneerator());
      values.add(oPerson);
    }

    return values;
  }

  private String randomStringGeneerator()
  {
      String[] sample = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
      String result = "";
      Random oRandom = new Random();

      int length = oRandom.nextInt(10) + 5;
      for(int i = 0 ; i < length; i++)
      {
        result += sample[oRandom.nextInt(sample.length)];
      }

      return result;
  }  
}
```

The Person class:

```
public class Person
{
  private final SimpleIntegerProperty ID;
  private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;

  public Person(int ID, String lName)
  {
    this.ID = new SimpleIntegerProperty(ID);
    this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
  }

  public int getID()
  {
    return this.ID.get();
  }

  public void setID(int ID)
  {
    this.ID.set(ID);
  }

  public String getLastName()
  {
    return this.lastName.get();
  }

  public void setLastName(String lName)
  {
    this.lastName.set(lName);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    return "ID: " + ID + " value: " + lastName;
  }
}
```

What I expect is that the row should stay selected, even after updating the value in the table row.

Comment: good that you provided a [mcve], though there's some leeway on __M__ :) No need for threads, just f.i. a button that changes the selected item. Also, it looks like this code seems to replace all (at least many Persons), so the selection might get confused. That said: there are tons of bugs around all concrete selectionModels when it comes to modification of the data. Not keeping the selected index on replacing the item is just one of them, unfortunately. And not much to do about it: most bugs are routed in MultipleSelectionModel which is a package-private super ...

Comment: the clear-on-replace is covered by https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8186908 (reported against multiple mode, but holds for single selection as well)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response @kleopatra :). I was wondering whether it might be a bug in Java or not. It is sad though, I do not see it being fixed any time soon. I have found a work around for this, which is less of a hack than reselecting the rows, I will post it below.

Answer (score 1):

So it would appear that there is a solution for this problem, it is less of a hack than trying to re-selecting the rows.
Replace:

```
table.getItems().set(J, newPerson);
```

with:

```
table.getItems().get(J).setLastName(newPerson.getLastName());
table.refresh();
```

So setting the value of the Properties, updates the data in the model, and then we just do the refresh, which then repaints the UI. This is not the best solution, but still a solution.

Comment: you shouldn't need to refresh, provided the data is set up correctly